# 2-way communication between swift and objective-C in a swift project

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I have a swift project into which i have imported a objective-C project and the bridging header was automatically created. I am trying to build an application to book tickets. I am storing all the data collected across the views in a swift class object.

Now there are many tutorials to use swift files in objective c project and objective c files in swift project but none talk about the communication both ways.

I wanna reuse the object created in swift class in objective C class .

I have been using NSUserDefaults to do 2 way communication .

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `NSUserDefaults` as "bridge". ObjC can directly access swift classes, if they subclass `NSObject`.

Open Xcode target build settings, in search field, type `swift`. Find `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name`. Commonly, it will have something `Project-Swift.h`. In ObjC code import this header, and your swift classes and functions will be available in ObjC.

More information can be found in official documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: How do I use an object between Swift and Objective-C, by reference to share data to and fro, without using shared preferences. And thanks for the answer.